# Custom validation function - javascritpt

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a "order by SKU" page that checks if the SKUs exist in the database, and if so, display their name via ajax. So far so good, but I'm having trouble disabling the submit button if errors are found.

```
function sku_check(){

    // Definir array de erros e começar incrementação
    var haErros = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    console.log(haErros);

    jQuery(".enc-cod-tab").each(function(){
    var tudo = jQuery(this);

    // Incrementar posição no array
        ++i

    jQuery(this).find("#remover").click(function() {
        jQuery(tudo).remove();
    });

    jQuery(this).keyup(function(){


    var input_cod = jQuery(this).find("#sku");
    var tick = jQuery(this).find("#tick");
    var cross = jQuery(this).find("#cross");
    var nome_do_produto = jQuery(this).find("#nome_do_produto");
    var codigo_inexistente = jQuery(this).find("#codigo_inexistente");

    var sku = jQuery(input_cod).val();

    if(sku == "" || sku.length < 7){
        jQuery(input_cod).css('border', '1px #CCC solid');
        jQuery(tick).hide();
        jQuery(nome_do_produto).hide();
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/verificar_cod.php",
            data: 'sku='+ sku,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                if(response.length > 0){
                    jQuery(input_cod).css('border', '1px #090 solid');
                    jQuery(tick).fadeIn();
                    jQuery(cross).hide();
                    jQuery(nome_do_produto).html(response);
                    jQuery(nome_do_produto).fadeIn();
                    jQuery(codigo_inexistente).hide();
                    haErros[i] = 'falso';
                    //jQuery("#btn_adicionar").css("opacity", 1);
                    //jQuery("#btn_adicionar").removeAttr("disabled")
                } else {
                    jQuery(input_cod).css('border', '1px #C33 solid');
                    jQuery(cross).fadeIn();
                    jQuery(tick).hide();
                    jQuery(nome_do_produto).hide();
                    jQuery(codigo_inexistente).fadeIn();
                    haErros[i] = 'verdadeiro';
                    //jQuery("#btn_adicionar").css("opacity", 0.2);
                    //jQuery("#btn_adicionar").attr("disabled", "disabled")}
                }
            }
        })
    }

    })

    // Função para ver se há erros
    jQuery(this).keydown(function(){
    if (jQuery.inArray("verdadeiro", haErros) != -1){
        jQuery("#btn_adicionar").css("opacity", 0.2);
        jQuery("#btn_adicionar").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    } else {
        jQuery("#btn_adicionar").css("opacity", 1);
        jQuery("#btn_adicionar").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    });

    })};
```

As you can see, I'm trying to insert in a array the values "falso" if there are no erros, and "verdadeiro" if ajax failed to retrieve the SKU from the database. Then, inside the "keyup" function, I'm checking for the value "verdadeiro" in the array and if that exists, the submit button becomes disabled.

This is only working on the second (and so forth) SKU input and ONLY after I mistype a SKU by 2 or more letters.

Example: sku123 exists. If I type "sku1234" it doesn't disable the submit button, but if I type "sku12345" then it works as expect.

Any idea on what's going on?

Comment: So basically you're saying: disabling the button works when `response.length` is 0. Can I assume your ajax request returns a result when you pass "sku1234"?

Makes me wonder how you determine which string is valid and which is false ...

Comment: Yes you can. It returns the product the product URL if it exists, otherwise the response is NULL.

Comment: Have you tried printing out the response to console or set breakpoints to debug the data?